# Can't rbind a data frame to an empty data frame

Tags: r, rbind

I'm learning R Studio and this is for a project I'm working on. I'm using the Marvel API to get a list of all of the characters in the universe by using a for loop to call the API multiple times. They API limits you to 100 results/call, so I'm iterating and setting the offset for each loop.

My code was working the last few days, however when I loaded up today and tried to fetch the data, I'm getting the error: "Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : invalid list argument: all variables should have the same length"

Here's the code that I'm running:

```
MarvelUniverse = data.frame()
y = 1
offset = c(0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400)
for(x in offset){
  partialUrl = "https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey={apiKey}&hash={hash}&limit=100&offset="  
  url = paste(partialUrl, offset, sep="")
  call = httr::GET(url[y])
  query = httr::content(call, as="raw")
  name = jsonlite::fromJSON(rawToChar(query))
  df = flatten(as.data.frame(name))
  MarvelUniverse = rbind(df, MarvelUniverse)
  y = y + 1
}
```

Since I was binding to an empty data frame before, I don't understand why I was able to use this function before, but it's failing now? I did notice that `df` is now holding 1618 elements where it was holding ~1498 prior to the break. The `name` list is still holding a large list of 7 elements, so that seems to be the same.

**EDIT**
I found that if I remove flatten from `df = flatten(as.data.frame(name))`, the call will execute over the first iteration of the loop, but now I'm running into an issue with duplicate row.names. Trying to set those to NULL, but unfortunately no luck so far.

Comment: Why not store the GET responses to a list, and then bind it all together in the end, like with `dplyr::bind_rows` or `Reduce` & `rbind`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- Don't `rbind()` data frames one at a time in a loop - this is a classic anti-pattern. It's called "growing an object" and is the [2nd Circle of Hell in the R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/). It's very inefficient. Rather, you should put all your data frames in a list, and `rbind` them all at once at the end.
- You're using two looping variables in the same loop: `x` and `y`. `x` is the one specified in `for()`, and `y` you are keeping track of manually. This is prone to bugs - just use one looping variable (almost always it's best to have the looping variable go over 1, 2, 3, ..., n)

Addressing these issues, I would try this code:

```
MarvelUniverseList = list()
offset = c(0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400)
for(i in seq_along(offset)){
  partialUrl = "https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey={apiKey}&hash={hash}&limit=100&offset="  
  url = paste(partialUrl, offset[i], sep="")
  call = httr::GET(url[i])
  query = httr::content(call, as="raw")
  name = jsonlite::fromJSON(rawToChar(query))
  MarvelUniverseList[[i]] = flatten(as.data.frame(name))
}

## combine at end
MarvelUniverse = do.call(rbind, MarvelUniverseList)

## more efficient and flexible version from dplyr
MarvelUniverse = dplyr::bind_rows(MarvelUniverseList)
```

Of course, without an API key, I can't test this or see what your problems are. `dplyr::bind_rows` is a bit more flexible than `rbind`, so it may solve your problem. But this approach also has the advantage that if there is an issue combining the data frames, you have the individual data frames stored in the list and you can inspect/debug/fix them so that they can be combined.

Comment: Thank you for that very in-depth break-down. This successfully pulls all of the data into a list for me. I know before when I was passing it as a data frame and it was working, it was keeping the ~38 variables as column headers - is there an easy way to re-assemble a data frame from the list? Apologies if this is a very rudimentary question.

Comment: Each list item is a data frame, and the last two lines of code I show are ways to combine those individual data frames into a single data frame.

Comment: I found where I was falling short - needed to go deeper into the returned array to get the specific list that I was looking for. All of the data was combined in a data frame where it was very messy. I extracted the two variables that I needed with all of the elements related to them. Thanks again for your help, Gregor Thomas.